# Running neo4j-Python code in Eclipse with Pydev under ArchLinux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, neo4j

so I installed neo4j on ArchLinux ([AUR Link](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=48435)) and want to test it using python 3.2.
I am using python 3.2, Eclipse with Pydev.

I tried following code from the neo4j website, allthough I think it was still 2.7 python code and I tried to convert it to Python 3.2 code.

Here's the code:

```
import os 
libpath = '/usr/share/java/neo4j' 
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = ';'.join( [ os.path.abspath(p) for p in 
os.listdir(libpath)]) 

from neo4j import GraphDatabase

# Create a database
db = GraphDatabase('/home/USERNAME/.db/neo4j/HelloWorld')

# All write operations happen in a transaction
with db.transaction:
    firstNode = db.node(name='Hello')
    secondNode = db.node(name='world!')

    # Create a relationship with type 'knows'
    relationship = firstNode.knows(secondNode, name='graphy')

# Read operations can happen anywhere
message = ' '.join([firstNode['name'], relationship['name'], secondNode['name']])

print(message)

# Delete the data
with db.transaction:
    firstNode.knows.single.delete()
    firstNode.delete()
    secondNode.delete()

# Always shut down your database when your application exits
db.shutdown()
```

But I get following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USERNAME/PATH/TO/src/neo4j-HelloWorld.py", line 12, in <module>
    from neo4j import GraphDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/neo4j_embedded-1.6-py3.2.egg/neo4j/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from neo4j.core import GraphDatabase, Direction, NotFoundException, BOTH, ANY, INCOMING, OUTGOING
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/neo4j_embedded-1.6-py3.2.egg/neo4j/core.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _backend import *
ImportError: No module named _backend
```

I just can't figure out what's wrong! 
I tried to set the CLASSPATH as described [here](http://neo4j.org/nabble/#nabble-td3358482), but it doesn't change anything.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run the code through `2to3`?

If not, I suggest you do.

I think the problem is that the relative import syntax changed in 3.x, see [PEP328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for details.

e.g. the offending import in `core.py` should *probably* say `from ._backend import *`

Comment: Didn't work for me though: the core.py when translated by 2to3 doesn't get it's references edited to suit ._backend import *